# Informing User after Generating a Large Excel File in PHP

Tags: php, phpexcel, large-files, timeoutexception

What is the best way to generate an excel file and inform the user after that?

I am using **PHPExcel** to generate an excel file from an **MSSQL** Server to a webserver and allow a user to download it using a link. The problem is that the each time we try to execute the PHP script it always throws a **fast-cgi timeout error**. The script needs to read up to 2000 - 5000 rows of data.

We tried to execute it via command prompt using `exec()` and Shell. It successfully generates the file in the server, but we don't have a way/method in informing the user after the script is completed.

Answer (score 0):

`exec()` should return the result of running the external program - can't you use it? You can move generated file to a directory that is reachable for user and just give him the URL to the file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Rafał Swacha . We already have tried this but the problem is that a fast-cgi error occurred at the page that executes the `exec()` command.